# Given factorization A = QR where Q's columns are pairwise orthogonal, but not orthonormal, how do i normalize Q's columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My questions is:

Given a factorization A = QR  where Q's columns are pairwise orthogonal, but not orthonormal, how do i normalize Q's columns while transforming R so result is still equal to A ?

I am working on an assignment where we are developing a solver for matrix equations based on a gram schmidt-like approach to QR factorization.

Given a matrix A, I have developed a routine  to compute Q^ and R^ where

```
       A = Q^ * R^            (read this as:  A = Q-hat * R-hat)
```

Q^ is not normalized, but the columns are pair-wise orthogonal

Normalization basically involves dividing each column 
vector in Q^ by the norm of that vector.. to maintain the equality 
A = Q^ * R^ (A = Q-hat * R-hat)
we need to apply some matrix operations to Q^, and some corresponding matrix operations to 
R^ to maintain the equality

So we need to figure out M and M', where:

```
        A = Q^ * M * R^ * M'
```

and Q^ * M gives an orthogonal matrix (wherein columns are both pairwise orthogonal AND ORTHONORMAL)

[[ Please note that in the discussion below  Q^ = QM and  R^ = RM (sorry i ended up using two  variable names for same thing) ]]

Anyway, below is an example of what we get from my routine.

First .. here is my 'A' matrix

print(A)

```
  0 1
  -----
  0 | 4 1
  1 | 3 2
  2 | 1 3
```

Now, here is the factorization:

```
Qlist, Rlist = aug_orthonormalize(L)

QM=coldict2mat(Qlist) # change from list of column vectors represenation to matrix representation.
RM=coldict2mat(Rlist)
LM=coldict2mat(L)
```

We see the factorization works out !

print(QM*RM)

```
0 1
-----
0 | 4 1
1 | 3 2
2 | 1 3
```

However, the columns of QM are not normalized.

print(QM)

```
0 1
-------
0 | 4 -1
1 | 3 0.5
2 | 1 2.5
```

We need to divide each column vector in QM by the norm of that vector and adjust RM accordingly.
 But let's try something even simpler. Let's try to multiply the first column of QM by 1/4 
 and then let's figure out what to multiply RM with so that the equality still holds. If I could figure out just how to do this, I could extend the process so that instead of 1/4th, I multiply the first vector by the inverse of its norm, and then do the same to each subsequent vector. But let's just start out with the goal of modifying first column vector of QM (a.k.a Q^) by 1/4 and then applying a 'correcting' transformation to RM (a.k.a R^) such that:

```
A = Q^ * M * R^ * M'
```

M is shown below:

construct M so that it divides first col of Q^  by 1/4

```
normFactor = 4
M = listlist2mat([[1/normFactor ,0],[0, 1]] ) 

print (M) 

0 1
--------
0 | 0.25 0
1 | 0 1
```

My first guess as to what M' should be was that it should be the inverse of M, so we can undo the division of first vector of Q^ by 4. In order to undo that, I thought we would simply multiply whatever came out of

```
Q^ * M * R^
```

by M-inverse , and then obtain A.  As shown below...

```
Minverse = Mprime = listlist2mat([[normFactor ,0],[0, 1]] ) 
print (Mprime ) 

0 1
-----
0 | 4 0
1 | 0 1

# They are inverses ! 
#
print (M * Mprime ) 

0 1
-----
0 | 1 0
1 | 0 1
```

So... let's see if Mprime 'undoes' the operations of M

```
print(QM * M * RM * Mprime )

0 1
---------
0 | 4 -0.5
1 | 3 0.875
2 | 1 2.62
```

Does not work out ;^(

```
assert A == QM * M * RM * Mprime 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

Try multiplying setting Mprime = M

```
print(QM * M * RM * M )

0 1
--------------
0 | 0.25 -0.5
1 | 0.188 0.875
2 | 0.0625 2.62
```

That does not work out either.. I am so stuck ;^(

Just taking this simple case where I scale the first vector of Q^.. what transformation do i need to apply to R^ so that it undoes that scaling operation applied to the first vector ?

thanks very much in advance !
Chris

UPDATE - 
thanks to great answer from James and Will  I have the solution..

print(QM * M  *    Mprime * RM  )

```
       0 1
     -----
 0  |  4 1
 1  |  3 2
 2  |  1 3
```

Why didn't they tell me that in class ;^(

Oh well ..  i got it, and I am happy.  Thanks again, gentlemen.

Update #2 - 
****  So, as a thank you, i donated 10 bucks to MIT Open courseware... I am working through Strang's very excellent linear algebra class through that site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evidently you are replacing $Q$ with $QD,$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Therefore replace $R$ by $D^{-1} R.$

Meanwhile, the entries of $D$ are the reciprocals of the Euclidean lengths of the relevant columns. So, the entries of $D^{-1}$ are the Euclidean lengths themselves.

Comment: As a rule, I'd tend to upvote this answer since it's good, but at the moment I'm only upvoting questions. In about 12 more votes I'll return here.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook, you are a diligent man.

Comment: Or, perhaps I seek fools gold. I'm not sure which.

Comment: Thanks for your response !      Any reference as to how i go about computing the diagnonal matrix D  ?

Comment: @ChrisBedford, I just typed it in. Do some 2 by 2 examples by hand. Multiplying by a diagonal matrix on the right multiplies each column by something. Multiplying by a diagonal matrix on the left multiplies each row by something.

Comment: Massively helpful (I'm in the same class as Chris). Now I can see where I was going wrong and how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You insert elementary matrices and their inverses in the middle of $QR$. If we put $QE^{-1}ER$ then we have $ER$ as a row operation, but $QE^{-1}$ as a column operation. This would seem to solve your problem.

Comment: I suspect I am saying the same as Will Jagy. The elementary matrices I have in mind just multiply a row by a nonzero number (so they're diagonal).

Comment: James, yes, of course.

Comment: You guys absolutely RULE !   Thank you so much..  I tried it it.. and it works..     I will add an update to the original post to show how it worked.